# Resize and Watermark Image PHP

Tags: php, image, image-processing

Could someone help with the following PHP code, please.

I am wanting to resize and add watermark to the uploaded image - here is the code...

```
$image = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
$image_name = $_FILES['file']['name'];

$image_size = getimagesize($image);
$image_width = $image_size[0];
$image_height = $image_size[1];

// Resizes image to roughly 150px by 100px
$new_size_small = ($image_width + $image_height)/($image_width * ($image_height / 75));

$new_width_small = $image_width * $new_size_small;
$new_height_small = $image_height * $new_size_small;

$location_small = "Product Images/Small Images/{$image_name}";

$new_image_small = imagecreatetruecolor($new_width_small, $new_height_small);

$source_image = imagecreatefromjpeg($image);    

imagecopyresampled($new_image_small, $source_image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $new_width_small, $new_height_small, $image_width, $image_height);   

$location_watermark = "Graphics/coming_soon.png";

$watermark = imagecreatefrompng($location_watermark);

$watermark_width = imagesx($watermark);
$watermark_height = imagesy($watermark);

$image_watermark = imagecreatetruecolor($watermark_width, $watermark_height);

imagecopymerge($image_watermark, $source_image, $new_width_small, $new_height_small, 0, 0, $watermark_width, $watermark_height, 100);

imagejpeg($image_watermark, $location_small, 100);
```

Once the image is uploaded, it should resize to roughly 150px by 100px and then save into the following folder on the server (Product Images/Small Images/)

I am able to resize the image successfully but once I apply the watermark code it stops working!

Answer (score 0):

Let's examine what you're doing here.

(1) Load the watermark image into memory

```
$watermark = imagecreatefrompng($location_watermark);
```

(2) Fetch the dimensions of this image

```
$watermark_width = imagesx($watermark);
$watermark_height = imagesy($watermark);
```

(3) Create a *new* (empty) image with these dimensions

```
$image_watermark = imagecreatetruecolor($watermark_width, $watermark_height);
```

(4) Then paste your source image on top of this empty watermark-sized image

```
imagecopymerge($image_watermark, $source_image, $new_width_small, $new_height_small, 0, 0, $watermark_width, $watermark_height, 100);
```

You kind of lost me at step (3). Can't you just delete that line and copy your watermark into the source image instead?

```
imagecopymerge($source_image, $watermark, 0, 0, 0, 0, $watermark_width, $watermark_height, 100);
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. 

I have tried removing the line you suggested but the image it creates is a blank white image (correct size) but no watermark! 

Here is the code:

`imagecopymerge($source_image, $watermark, 0, 0, 0, 0, $watermark_width, $watermark_height, 100);`

Code to upload:

`imagejpeg($source_image, $location_small, 100);`